# There are errors when using Intel DPC++ compiler to compile subroutine with Eigen head file

Tags: c++, intel, eigen, dpc++

Just got stuck in compiling a simple C++ program with Eigen C++ when using intel oneAPI DPC++/C++ compiler:
The example contains two .cpp files (main.cpp and Preprocessing.cpp) and one include file (struct_INFO.h).

I don't know why the compiler gives errors as the image shows.
[Error messages from Intel compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjD9U.png):

```
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<bool>
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<char>
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<signed char> 
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<unsigned char>
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<wchar_t>
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<char16_t>
duplicate symbol: bool const std::_Is_integral<char32_t>
```

...
All the errors are similar, so I just show some of them.

It seems that I can include neither the Eigen head file (<Eigen/Core>) nor the head file struct_INFO.h, which containing Eigen head file, in my subroutine Preprocessing.cpp.

The only way that I know to fix the problem is to merge the two .cpp files into one.

However, this approach is kind of cumbersome that I need to put all the subroutines in one file as long as I need to use the Eigen variables.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

1. main.cpp:

   ```
   #include "struct_INFO.h"
   #include <Eigen/Core>

   int Preprocessing(struct_INFO& struct_INFO_obj);

   int main(int* argc, char** argv)
   {
       struct_INFO struct_INFO_obj;
       Preprocessing(struct_INFO_obj);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Preprocessing.cpp

   ```
   #include "struct_INFO.h"

   int Preprocessing(struct_INFO& struct_INFO_obj)
   {
          return 1;
   }
   ```
3. struct_INFO.h

   ```
   #include <Eigen/Core>

   class struct_INFO
   {
          public:
          Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Matrix;
   };
   ```

Comment: You should use three ticks \`\`\`cpp code here \`\`\` to format code blocks and please use newlines in there. Also if you provide console output, please do so as text, as one cannot easily copy from a picture.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the format. This is my first time to post a question here.  I tried to follow the format, but somehow didn't make it right. Thank you again!

Comment: Compiles+links fine with ICX on https://godbolt.org/z/5ThMvr163, with Eigen 3.4.  The resulting asm doesn't define any of those symbols in the first place.  But Godbolt can't test with multiple compilation units linking together.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for editing your question. Someone was faster than me and edited your question again because your edit still bungled some code formatting. You should have a look at the used syntax as it makes it easier to understand your question.

Comment: Are you just missing an include guard or a #pragma once in `struct_INFO.h`?

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thank you for help. I am still trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @Eike, you are right. Thanks for the one who helped edit my post. I tried some ways such as using #ifndef and #define, but the compiler still shows the same errors. I just tried your suggestion using #pragma once. There are still the same errors shown up.